# Commuting between Symmetric Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I had a homework question that asked to give an example of a subgroup of $S_4$ that is not normal.  I found such an example but I'm not sure why it worked.  If I understand  the normalizer correctly the question reduces to finding two elements (one in $S_4$ and one in a subgroup of $S_4$) such that the two elements do not commute.  Is that a correct interpretation?  If so, how can you tell whether or not two elements commute without testing them.

Comment: No, that interpretation is not correct at all... a subgroup $\;H\;$ of a group $\;G\;$ is **not** normal if you can find some elements $\;h\in H\,,\,\,g\in G\;$ s.t. $\;h^g:=g^{-1}hg\notin H\;$. Nothing to do with commutativity.

Comment: Why couldn't you just multiply both sides by g on the left to get gh = hg?

Comment: Because *not necessarily* $\;g^{-1}hg=h\;$ ! We can only ask that $\;g^{-1}hg=h'\in H\;$, but it may well be that $\;h\neq h'\;$